# Any way to set vim's colorcolumn in git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

In vim, I can use `set colorcolumn=80` to highlight the column 80.

I need same functionality in `git diff`, any way to do this?

Comment: Why not set your difftool to vim?

Comment: @gregory how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using vim (vimdiff) using this command:

```
git difftool --tool=vimdiff --no-prompt
```

If this is something you like, you can configure git to always use vim as its difftool and merge tool:

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Once you're using vimdiff, familiarize yourself with common actions:

```
]c :        - next difference
[c :        - previous difference
do          - diff obtain
dp          - diff put
zo          - open folded text
zc          - close folded text
:diffupdate - re-scan the files for differences
```

You'll gain all the niceties of vim (coloring, macros, modal editing) but you'll be in a specialized mode of vim designed for diffs and merges.

Answer (score -2):

maybe,you can google **vim script**, most of vim extensions use vim script to implement some function.

Comment: The answer doesn't answer anything. The question is not about `vim`.